# Integration between a Python script and Java program

Tags: java, python

I fiddled around with calling a python script from a Java program for a little while and was finally able to get it working. However, When I called it I noticed that there is a certain call in the python script that creates an object that takes a couple of seconds (which is longer than I'd like). So in an essence every time the script runs it has to re-import a few libraries and create a new object. I'm not sure if this is even possible, but is there any way to keep the python script in a state where it wouldn't have to completely re-run from the start every single time?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I do not have much experience with the integration of programs with different languages.

Thank you very much!!! Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Google's [Protobuf](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/). It is basically a cross-language RPC.

Or open a named pipe between your java and python application

Comment: I know what piping is from my experience with UNIX but am not completely sure how I would use it here. This would probably be what I want to do though. Or I have read another possibility is working with Jython. I will take a look at these options.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm not sure if this is even possible, but is there any way to keep the python script in a state where it wouldn't have to completely re-run from the start every single time?

The correct and most obvious way to do this is to re-implement (*if you can*) the Python script and turn it into some kind of **Remote Serivce** and use some kind of **Interface**:

Examples:

- Web Service over JSON
- Web Service over RPC, JSON-RPC, XML-RPC

You would then access the service(s) remotely over a network connection from your Java program and serialize parameters passed to the Python program and theh results back to Java via something both can speak eaisly. e.g: JSON

Comment: I see what you mean there. I guess if I set it up correctly then I could just do something like a GET with a parameter and I would have my result in JSON.